# how to control a embedded multiframe swf file?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, movieclip

`[Embed(source="data/fire.swf")] static public var movieFire:Class;`

I have some multiframe swf file and I want to have control of them. For example, I can use gotoandplay and gotoandstop functionality.

I tried something like:
`var m:MovieClip = new movieFire() as MovieClip;` but it turns out when I tried to get totalFrames, `m.totalFrames`, it gives me zero, and gotoand* functions don't work either. How can I correctly control the swf file embedded in actionsript 3.0 (No Flex component)?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need make swf file, where is needed movieClips exported for actionscript. After what you need embed these symbols to your flex code:

```
    [Embed(source="../lib/trash.swf", symbol="emptytrash")]
    private static const _trash:Class;
    private static var trash:MovieClip = new _trash();
```

in [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) can you easily do that.

Don't forget to publish SWF in actionscript 3 language and same version, as you use for compiling flex application.